# VS 2008 Express - clickOnce question

Tags: visual-studio, deployment

I have the VS Express 2008 where there is only ClickOnce deployment option. I need my app to be simple ran by clicking on the exe file without any installation.
I have found out that after deleting both manifests and icon /which is always in the output directory even though its embedd with "Do not copy" option/ it works well. Is it ok or is there any cleaner way how to do that?   I mean, if the app is not being installed but only ran, do I still need external manifest files? I tried to embedd them but these still persist external (tried "Embed manifest with default setting" option or add my own and selected from list).

EDIT: In the Express, there is only ClickOnce.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run it from the *exe*, ClickOnce isn't quite right. ClickOnce executes as a `.application`, and you should be able to just click the radio button (on the "Publish" tab) for "The application is available online only", which avoids any local ClickOnce install.

Otherwise, just build as Release and take the /bin/Release output; this is your standalone exe app. To get the right trust, a .NET exe can be executed from:

- local drives
- *mapped* network drives (f: etc) with the right .NET service pack
- anywhere if "caspol" has been used to set a policy

Answer (score 0):

I believe in Visual Studio Express, ClickOnce deployment is your only choice.